# JPA - Secondary Table mapping direction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've got two tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Checkin (
  ID int primary key,
  foo varchar(100),
  bar varchar(100),
  FK_type int foreign key references Type(ID)
)

CREATE TABLE Type (
  ID int primary key,
  type varchar(100)
)
```

Since the secondary table only stores labels, I'd like to map the values directly into my entity. I figured it should be possible using @SecondaryTable...

```java
@Table(name = "Checkin")
@SecondaryTable(name = "Type",
    pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="FK_type", referencedColumnName = "ID")
)
class Checkin {
  @Id
  private Integer id;

  private String foo;
  private String bar;

  @Column(name="FK_type", table="Type")
  private String type;
}
```

Unforunately, it would seem that the @SecondaryTable annotation works the other way around, meaning it wants my actual primary data table with the most columns to be the one joining. So I get thrown the error

```
Invalid column name 'FK_type'.
```

Is there a way to solve that through different annotations or do I really need to build the whole construct the other way round and have the main entity refer to "Type" and "Chekin" be the secondary table?

Answer (score 0):

You should join Type entity in Checkin:

```
class Checkin {
      @Id
      private Integer id;
    
      private String foo;
      private String bar;
    
      @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
      private Type type;
    }
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid in first place. Could obviously use a getter to return the actual String, but that would have side effects because we're using lombok quite a bit, so loading the value instead of mapping the whole thing as an entity would be ideal

Comment: I have no idea)

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct this:

```java
@Column(name="FK_type", table="Type")
private String type;
```

to this:

```java
@Column(name="type", table="Type")
private String type;
```

The table `Type` just do not have the `FK_type` column, as I understand you want to use `Type.type` here.

P.S. You can omit to use `referencedColumnName` if this is a reference to the PK.

Comment: Doesn't solve the issue. FK_type in the PkJoinColumn annotation throws an Exception (com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'FK_Type'), which seems logical, judging by the Documentation of PkJoinColumn.
name is defined as "The name of the primary key column of the current table"
referencedColumnName The name of the primary key column of the table being joined to.
So my assumption is that - as described in the original post - the Secondary table is supposed to have a foreign key reference to my primary table. Doesn't make much sense in my use case though...